# convert generic code from c# to template c++

Tags: c#, c++, templates, generics

I try to convert this code (c# code) to c++ code

```
public abstract class IGID<T>
    where T : IGID<T>
```

how do i implement such a template condition in c++ ?

Comment: What does it do in C#?

Comment: I don't think you can

Comment: There's no such thing in C++, and there is no *need* for such a thing in C++. C# generics are reified at runtime, while C++ templates are instantiated at compile time. So if a constraint isn't satisfied, the code will fail to compile. I guess you could use `static_assert` though if you *really* want it.

Comment: My C# is rusty, but does this code really require that T is a / inherits from `IGID<T>` ? So a valid object needs the type `IGID<A> == IGID<IGID<B>> == IGID<IGID<IGID<C>>>` and so on ... infinte levels.

Comment: Whatever the solution it will involve some form of [`static_assert`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd293588(v=vs.110).aspx), now what that assert would need to contain, I am not sure.

Comment: it work very good in c# (there is no infinity loop)..

Answer (score 4):

The best you could do is throw a `static_assert` in an empty base class that will fire on construction. You have to delay until use because all the types have to complete before you can do any such checking.

We have our assertion object:

```
template <typename C>
struct Require {
    Require() {
        static_assert(C::value, "!");
    }
};
```

It's empty, so adds no overhead. And then we have:

```
template<typename T>
struct IGID : Require<std::is_base_of<IGID<T>, T>>
{
};
```

Even though `T` is incomplete here, we don't check anything until `IGID<T>` is constructed, so we're okay.

```
struct A : IGID<A> { }; // okay
```

But:

```
struct B : IGID<int> { }; 

main.cpp:8:9: error: static_assert failed "!"
        static_assert(C::value, "!");
        ^             ~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:13:8: note: in instantiation of member function 'Require<std::is_base_of<IGID<int>, int> >::Require' requested here
struct IGID : Require<std::is_base_of<IGID<T>, T>>
       ^
```